# How to change the default volume name in the /media path?

Tags: mount, gvfs

When I mount the logical volume through Unity dash or the File Manager it creates the mount point at `/media/$USER/557808d2-b3a5-4bf2-b84b-93a3b42ce36a`.

I want to change the volume label from 557808d2-b3a5-4bf2-b84b-93a3b42ce36a to some simple string like 'data' and keep it as it is permanently, so that it wont change next time when I mount it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the "Disks" utility, look for your Disk > Volume.

[image]

Once you have select the partition "unmount" it ,click the "Cog" icon, then select "Edit File partition". Change the label and mount it again. Done.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way:

if Filesystem is Fat32

```
sudo mlabel -i /dev/sda1 ::new-label
```

else

```
sudo e2label /dev/sda1 "new-label"
```